# Does JavaScript guarantee object property order during declaration?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

For example:

```js
var f=function(str){
  console.log(str);
  return str;
};
var obj={
  a:f('value A'),
  b:f('value B'),
};

//some other code
```

does it guarantee

```
value A
value B
```

instead of

```
value B
value A
```

is printed?

Note: I'm asking the order of execution of f(), not the order of keys of Object.keys(obj).

Comment: No it does not, objects never guarantee order

Comment: Yes, but only in native es6 compliant implementations. So don't count on it.

Comment: Yes it does, and not just in ES6. You're asking about the order of execution of the functions, and its order is guaranteed. Comments above are confusing this question with the order of visitation of properties during enumeration.

Comment: @Barmar: That's not a duplicate.

Comment: @SkinnyPete Yes, misunderstood the question, reopened.

Comment: @charlietfl: The `f` function could return an object that contains an index that is incremented on each call, thereby recording the creation order of the properties and establishing an actual, reliable order for sorting or other purposes.

Comment: The [relevant bit of the specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-propertydefinitionevaluation) essentially says to (recursively) handle the properties before the final comma, then the property after that comma, which implies a standardized order.

Comment: I'll +1 this question.  It considers different aspects of event execution & ordering and object/property creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Even though this is clearly a duplicate of [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order), I'll go ahead and answer anyway.</s>

There is *zero guarantee* of order in your "unordered collection of properties". However with modern implementations of Javascript, you can expect that the properties will *usually* be in order as you defined them.

As long as the expected order is preferable, but not critical, it is reasonable in most cases to just assume they will be in order. But if your business logic depends on that order to be guaranteed, then you definitely need to rethink your strategy.

Okay. I see now what you are actually asking. In this particular context, the answer is "yes and no".

Your functions are being called statically as your object is being defined. So the function defining property `a` will always be called before the function defining property `b`.

However, `console.log` is an asynchronous function, and you cannot rely on it to log `value A` before it logs `value B`

Comment: Read the comments above. The concept of an unordered collection has no bearing on the order of the evaluation of its members in its initializer.

Comment: ...take this example: `var i = 0; var obj = {a:++i, b:++i, c:++i};` The key/value pairs will reliably be `a:1`, `b:2`, and `c:3`. Enumerating the object may not visit them in that order, but the pairings will be sure. Imagine how confusing it would be if the initializing order wasn't guaranteed.